# Vim paste string with non-ASCII characters

Tags: vim, paste

I am trying to paste a string from a register in VIM which contains non-ASCII characters such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>, how can I paste this string into a file, but escape the non-ASCII characters automatically?

Essentially, what I am trying to achieve is recording a macro which has some (non-ascii) characters, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> which vim will show as ^W.  I want to be able to take the macro (by examining the registers and taking the macro string (i.e @a=^W)) and copying it into a .vimrc file as a key-map, so that when I press the key it will run that macro.

I want to do this automatically (or as fast as possible) without having to change ^W into <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> in the .vimrc file, or wherever I paste it too.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/683727/vim-escaping-non-ascii-value-for-pasting/683784#683784; please don't post in parallel to multiple Stack Exchange sites!

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL-V` allows you to insert non-ASCII characters into VIM.

i.e. to insert `CTRL-W` you need to press `CTRL-V` `CTRL-W`.